# I have bike tires that read 26 x 1.95. Does that mean I need a 26-inch tube?

Tags: innertube

I ask because my front tire's inner tube got torn and I needed to replace it.

It was 26 x 1.95 as well and I bought a 26 inch bike tube and it was too big -- inflated it would hang 2 inches off the rim and would not fit within the tread/tire part itself, and I am certain it's a 26 inch tire.

Comment: Please do learn to use the search functions of SE.  I found an exact duplicate straight away.  We have a lot of good answers to many questions, so any common question probably already has an answer.  Pre-answered for your convenience!

Answer (score 1):

Did you inflate the tube off the rim or without a tyre?  they stretch when inflated naked.

Read the tube side it might be a 27.5 in the wrong box.

Answer (score 0):

It will fit once its partially inflated. You need a 26 inch tube,with a range 26xa - b where a<= 1.95 and b>=1.95. Though, you could likely use a 26x2.00 tube just fine.